# GTK named stack childs

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am using a Gtk.Stack widget in PyGobject, and as i could not find any "tutorial" on how to use them, i supposed that each element of the Gtk.Stack has a name/tag.

And so i made a few elements and connected to the stack with:

```
add_named(element_to_add_to_stack, "Element_tag")
```

The fist of them was connected and successfully appeared, but whenever i set another as visible with:

```
set_visible_child_name("Element_tag")
```

Nothing happens, and after a retrieval of which elements are part of the stack:

```
stack.get_visible_child()
```

It simply returns

> None

What is wrong?  Is that way to use Gtk.Stack wrong?

Edit:

```
def main_content(self):
    right_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    self.stack = Gtk.Stack()
    self.stack.get_style_context().add_class("main-container")
    self.stack.props.margin = 20
    self.stack.add_named(self.gen_page1(), "page1")
    self.stack.add_named(self.gen_page2(), "page2")
    self.stack.add_named(self.gen_page3(), "page3")
    #self.stack.set_visible_child_name("page2")
    #self.stack.set_visible_child_full("page2", 1)
    print((self.stack.get_visible_child()))

    right_box.pack_start(self.stack, True, True, 0)
    return right_box
```

Comment: Can you show some more code. I suspect something else is wrong..

Comment: @drahnr Done. Neither of the commented code functions worked.
The print returns "None"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child widget needs to be visible (as in `Widget.get_visible()`) before it can be a 'visible child'. This is not the case at this point of your code (although it would just work when the window is actually shown), but if you just do `my_child_widget.set_visible (True)` before adding the child widgets to the stack, `get_visible_child()` should start working.

Not the greatest design really as the `set_visible_child*` functions fail totally silently...

Comment: Thanks. I though that every element was visible by default. In fact it could output something to sterr in case of such failure, it would be nice and save a lot of time.

Comment: Yeah, widgets not being visible by default is an annoying legacy thing. For reference, the documentation was just fixed to say "Note that the @child widget has to be visible itself (see gtk_widget_show()) in order to become the visible child of @stack".